# C# Using timer1_Tick to plot FastLine chart in realtime

Tags: c#, plot, charts

I am coding in C#, and I have 3 variables that are being updated via my timer every 1000ms.
I want to use this timer to have a FastLine chart that plots the new points every 1000ms obviously.
I have got this working to a certain extent.
It is plotting each tick the timer does, but it just keeps adding to it i only want it to show the previous 20 plots, not the past 2000 if the program has been running that long.

My code below for the chart within my timer1_Tick method:

```
try
{
       chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xaxis++, CPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
       chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(xaxis, NvdGPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
       chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(xaxis, ramusedpt);
}
catch
{
}
```

xaxis is declared previously as an int, no need to show all code as rest is irrelevant

Comment: You're discarding any exception this way, are you sure you're not getting some error that lets it "skip" some cycles and you simply don't realize it? Try catching an exception and see if it happens

Comment: i added exception catching and nothing, it works perfectly fine but it just keeps increasing the FastLine as it should ... but keeps the original point ... thus it's not staying one size it's  just increasing :/ @Leo

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about when you say "it's just increasing", anyway I'd say this "xaxis++" is increasing that value every time this routine is executed. Is this the issue?

Comment: I answered a similar question a while ago. Take a look and see if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667086/how-to-move-x-axis-grids-on-chart-whenever-a-data-is-added-on-the-chart/31679887#31679887

Comment: @Leo look at task manager charts for cpu etc. if it shows up to 20 points plotted, then it will plot up to20 points, 1 point every tick of the timer. When it hits 20 it needs to remove the first point and then it can plot the chart. Therefore realtime chart:P

Comment: @jstreet yes! thankyou perfect been looking for ages for something like that :)! thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch what the issue was! Good that you solved!

Comment: @JezykDanzowki you're welcome! Up votes never hurt anyone...:O)

Comment: no problem leo! probably my bad description ... it's pretty specific issue and just did @jstreet clean perfect code lucky you came here haha :D have a good day

Comment: @JezykDanzowki you don't need to re-post my answer, just a link to it is ok. Also, when an answer is useful to you, the proper thing to do is to up vote it, like explained here: [What is voting up?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: @JezykDanzowki I mean up voting the original answer i gave to someone else's question and that was useful to you, not only my comments here. Please take a tour on the help pages to learn how Stackoverflow works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is what was used to solve the problem, posted by the user jstreet
Link to the hread and his comment:
[How to move x-axis grids on chart whenever a data is added on the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667086/how-to-move-x-axis-grids-on-chart-whenever-a-data-is-added-on-the-chart/31679887#31679887)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
Timer timer;
Random random;
int xaxis;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    random = new Random();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xaxis++, random.Next(1, 7));

    if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 10)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Remove(chart1.Series[0].Points[0]);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = xaxis;
    }
}
```