# Automatically zoom in ripple of waveform

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I show my data in chart form. But the data from my sensor is always changing. How can I automatically zoom-in to the peak to peak value so that I can keep track of the waveform? For example, the Y-axis is showing 0 to 10, however, the data is varied between 4 to 4.2 or, sometimes, 6 to 6.3. These are a small ripple. If I keep the Y-axis interval to  0~10, I cannot see the waveform (only a straight line will be seen).I know how to manually zoom-in the Y-axis interval. Is there any method I can show the ripple automatically ?

```
            DataPoint dp0 = new DataPoint(x, index);
            DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(x, middle);
            DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(x, ring);
            chart3.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
            chart3.Series[0].Points.Add(dp0);
            chart4.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
            chart4.Series[0].Points.Add(dp1);
            chart5.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
            chart5.Series[0].Points.Add(dp2);
            x++;

private void numericUpDown3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((numericUpDown3.Value - (decimal)0.1) <= numericUpDown4.Value)
        {
            numericUpDown3.Value = numericUpDown4.Value + (decimal)0.1;
        }
        chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Convert.ToDouble(numericUpDown3.Value);

    }

    private void numericUpDown4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((numericUpDown4.Value + (decimal)0.1) >= numericUpDown3.Value)
        {
            numericUpDown4.Value = numericUpDown3.Value - (decimal)0.1;
        }
        chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(numericUpDown4.Value);

    }
```

Comment: @jstreet thanks for your answer, but do you have the example code for your suggestions? because I don't know how to make a rolling window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to [jstreet's rolling window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667086/how-to-move-x-axis-grids-on-chart-whenever-a-data-is-added-on-the-chart/31679887#31679887) you also have to set `AxisY.Minimum` and `AxisY.Maximum` as you already figured out.

When you apply jstreet's rolling window solution, your data set will always contain `N` `DataPoint`s. In his example code he uses `N=10`. If you take the minimum and maximum of your `DataPoint` set `chart3.Series[0].Points` to adjust your y-axis you will have a rolling window that automatically zooms in on the ripples as your data comes in:

```
using System.Linq;

...

chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 
    chart3.Series[0].Points.Min(dp => dp.YValues.Single());
chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 
    chart3.Series[0].Points.Max(dp => dp.YValues.Single());
```

Depending on the nature of your data you might notice some jitter in your presentation. If that becomes an issue you will have to smooth the values you use to adjust your y-axis.

Comment: thz for your answer. I get the following error when I use your code: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'DataPoint' does not contain a definition for 'Min' and no extension method 'Min' accepting a first argument of type 'DataPoint' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added the line `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: yes, I do. VS2015 gives a red underline to Min and Max.

Comment: I can't look into it right now, but try removing the `[0]` after each `.Points`. E.g., getting the minimum should look something like this: `chart3.Series[0].Points.Min(dp => dp.YValue);`.

Comment: Thz so much. the previous problem is gone, but now it underline the YVakue. 'DataPoint' does not contain a definition for 'YValue' and no extension method 'YValue' accepting a first argument of type 'DataPoint' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok, I see. It's `YValues` -- a collection of y-values (note the plural s). But in your case there should always only be a single y-value, right? So use `dp => dp.YValues.Single()` as selector for the `Min()` and `Max()` functions. I updated the answer accordingly.